# How to get a list of all vulnerability alerts in a GitHub organisation?

Tags: security, github, graphql, insomnia, dependabot

I'd like to get an overview, for example of all the critical vulnerabilities I have access to view in a GitHub organization.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66356941/1101109) has allowed me to get a list for a specific repository:

```
{
    repository(name: "repo-name", owner: "repo-owner") {
        vulnerabilityAlerts(first: 100) {
            nodes {
                createdAt
                dismissedAt
                securityVulnerability {
                    package {
                        name
                    }
                    advisory {
                        description
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However scanning a large organization manually is just as easy repo-by-repo through the GUI as it is through the API.

Is there a way, preferably in [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/download), though if not then a CLI version is ok, to get such a list of critical vulnerabilities?

I suspect it can only be done by querying every repo by iterating through the list of all repositories, something like this query I had from something else I was playing with, though was curious if anyone had any other clever solutions to save writing that app:

```
query{
    organization(login: "repo-owner"){
        repositories(first: 100){
            nodes{
                name
            }
            pageInfo{
                hasNextPage
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm unaware of a way to filter for critical vulnerabilities using the GitHub graphql, but you can do something like this:

```
{
  organization(login: "repo-owner") {
    repositories(first: 100) {
      nodes {
        nameWithOwner
        vulnerabilityAlerts(first: 10) {
          nodes {
            securityAdvisory {
              severity
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will output the severity for every single repository in the `repo-owner` organization regardless if there is a severity for the repository. I believe with the `gh` cli tool, you can use Go templates to format the output. For more information on how to use the `gh` cli tool with Go templating, please refer to the [following page](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api).

Comment: Definitely easier than going repo by repo, so it's a great start, thanks!